# How to create git workflow on heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, staging

```
        Production        
            ↑             
         Staging          
           ↗↘          
       Development        
         ↗↙ ↖↘          
  Developer1  Developer2
```

How to create git workflow on heroku?

Comment: What you draw looks like a good workflow, what are you asking for exactly?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if you have *one* Git repo on the Heroku side, or several.

With several repo, you can assign each one for a step in the development lifecycle.
But considering the architecture behind a Git repo, it might be easier to manage your [dynos in relation with one repo](http://www.heroku.com/how/scale) (see [here for more on Dynos](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos)).

That means you can define **one branch per development steps** (one `dev` branch, one `staging` branch, one `prod` branch) on the Heroku side (in your local repo, you can have as many branches as you need).

Comment: Using different branches is a good idea; here is the way to do that with Git on Heroku: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments#advanced_linking_local_branches_to_remote_apps